# Error installing windows and Ubuntu maximum number of partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

i want to install windows in my ubuntu pc, when i was installing ubuntu, i leaved a little space on my hard drive (Unlocated Space) so when i trying install on my `located space` i got an error like

> Windows Cannot Installed to this hardisk space, The selected disk has the maximum number of partition of this type

so what should i do ??

should i delete the `Disk 0 Partition 1 : System Reserved` ?

my partition disk list is in the link below :

[Partition List 1](https://pasteboard.co/GEVu93i.jpg)

any help will be appreciated

thanks

Comment: That means the drive partitioning scheme was setup as `msdos` and not `gpt`.  `msdos`partitioning is limited to 4 primary partitions.  `gpt` on the other hand is many more.  But to setup `gpt` you would have to repartition the drive to `gpt` which would wipe out your drive.

Comment: @Terrance, it is possible to do an MBR-to-GPT conversion without losing partitions. The `gdisk` tool in Ubuntu can do this; see [this page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html) for details. The trouble is that this will require re-installing a boot loader. Also, Windows requires EFI-mode booting when using a GPT disk, and it's not clear if the computer has that support. (Most sold since late 2011 do; most sold earlier do not.) The Windows version may also be relevant. In sum, more information is required to offer good suggestions.

Comment: What is your motherboard model?  There is a chance that your motherboard may not have UEFI.  Mine doesn't, so that is why I have two separate drives for Windows and Ubuntu.  My drives are formatted msdos so they can't support more than 4 primary partitions.  But the good news is, you can setup extended partitions to have as many logical as you want.  Actually, I think that Windows 10 uses a minimum of 3 primary partitions.  One boot, regular for the OS, and one for diags.